# How to print out elements of multiset of pair

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, multiset

```
multiset< pair<int,pair<int,int>> >ml;
pair<int,pair<int,int>> p;
p.first=3;
p.second.first=5;
p.second.second=2;
ml.insert(p);
```

That's how I insert in my multiset of pair of pair
But I don't know how to print out all elements in my multiset of pair of pair
I have tried that but it's not working

```
 multiset< pair<long long,pair<long long,long long> > >::iterator it;
      it=ml.begin(); 
   p=*it;
cout<<p.first<<" "<<p.second.first<<" "<<p.second.second<<endl;
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work, or not work? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate across the set (C++11 range-based for is good here):

```
for (auto x : ml)
{
    cout << "First: " << x.first <<" " << " Second first: " << x.second.first << " Second.second: " << x.second.second << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this. They are almost the same, but the second one is much shorter.

First approach:

```
for (multiset< pair<int, pair<int,int> > >::iterator it = ml.begin(); it!=ml.end(); it++) {
    cout<<"First: "<<it->first<<", Second: "<<it->second.first<<", Third: "<<it->second.second<<endl;
}
```

Second approach (only in C++11 and later):

```
for (auto it:ml) {
    cout<<"First: "<<it.first<<", Second: "<<it.second.first<<", Third: "<<it.second.second<<endl;
}
```

And the output is the same:

```
First: 3, Second: 5, Third: 2
```